# Am I doing it right while reading a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, .net-2.0

This code is trying to read a file but giving error,

```
   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\doc.ics' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
```

I think this is the code causing the problem while reading file, it  works fine on development and integration servers but not on production server.

```
    private byte[] ReadByteArrayFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        FileStream filestrm = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader binaryread = new BinaryReader(filestrm);
        long longNumBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
        buffer = binaryread.ReadBytes((int)longNumBytes);
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Do you close/dispose of the filestream anywhere? The answer is in the error message. Since it implements `IDisposable` consider wrapping it in a using block.

Comment: Not sure if this code is the reason of the exception, as you can see, before the FileStream call, the exception talks about a StreamWriter, search where your code try to WRITE to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing right: whenever you open a file stream, **you must dispose it**.

This will do the trick:

```
private byte[] ReadByteArrayFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;

        using(FileStream filestrm = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using(BinaryReader binaryread = new BinaryReader(filestrm))
        {
             long longNumBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
             buffer = binaryread.ReadBytes((int)longNumBytes);
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

`using` statements will call `Dispose()` for you, even if an exception is thrown!

*And, of course, you'll avoid file locking.*

[Take a look at this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @user13814 Nice! Take in account the other answerer and the usage of `File.ReadAllBytes`. It's also a good solution, but if you were looking to check why the file was locked, right, you got the answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"path");
```

Instead!

Comment: That's true. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `FileStream` inside `using` statement to ensure that it is properly closed and disposed:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    ...
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)