# What am not disposing while creating a iCal file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, .net-2.0, filestream

In reference to my question [Am I doing it right while reading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544432/am-i-doing-it-right-while-reading-a-file/15544557?noredirect=1#15544557)

I am using this code to create a iCal file but not sure if I am doing it right or need to dispose anything as getting this error,

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\doc.ics' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
```

Code I am using is,

```
    String filePath = paramUri.LocalPath.ToString().TrimStart("filePath:///".ToCharArray());
    int lastSlash = filePath.LastIndexOf('\\');
    if(lastSlash > 0)
    {
        String folderPath = filePath.Substring(0, lastSlash);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        if(!di.Exists)
            di.Create();
    }

    //Use a streamwriter to create a file in the location specified in the URI
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        //Autoflush enabled so we don't have to worry about closing the streamwriter
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        sw.WriteLine("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN");
        sw.WriteLine("VERSION:2.0");
        sw.WriteLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
        sw.WriteLine("X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE");
        //I am adding more details but they are not relevant to post
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is happening in the `StreamWriter` constructor, the file is probably not being locked by the code you have included.

I would guess that it is locked by another process, perhaps you have it open in a text editor?

Comment: when I implemented what has been asked in my first question, it fixed the issue, thanks :)